# Downloadable files in a new browser tab

Tags: extensions, articles, attachments

I have a problem: in an article, there are downloadable files.

I wish that all of these were open in a new browser tab, without having to set them one by one (+ 3000 pdf files).

Do you know of a ext / mod / plugin or another way to do this once and for all? Thx very much at all for the help

Comment: well that all depends how the download works exactly. Are you using some sort of extension? Is it a simply `href` attribute linking the user to the file?

Comment: it's a simply href attribute linking the user to the file

Comment: have you tried adding `target="_blank"` to your `<a>` tag?

Comment: If the URLs contain a unique property that you could target, this would be fairly easy with jQuery. `$('a[href^="somestring"]').attr('target', '_blank');`

Comment: I know that what but I would not to do it  one by one (+ 3000 pdf files).

Comment: A plugin can be written for this purpose. Also you can use jQuery for example: `$('a[href$=.pdf]').attr('target', '_blank');`

Comment: If they are in one article, you can copy the html source of this article and paste it in a good text editor and use "Find and Replace" command. Find `<a ` and replace with `<a target="_blank" ` (notice the trailing space). This will change all links including web links. For advanced Find/Replace you need an advanced editor which supports "Regular Expressions".

Answer (score 1):

[Regular Labs ReReplacer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/rereplacer) or [Regular Labs DB Replacer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/db-replacer) can probably help with this by replacing instances of `<a href` with `<a target="_blank" href` or similar.